# Can you lose a badge if criteria is no longer met?

Tags: support, badges

I was awarded the tumbleweed badge for the question linked below (thanks a bunch for all your help guys !)

[PYTHON Set outline color for a barplot](https://superuser.com/questions/1288135/python-set-outline-color-for-a-barplot)

My question is, if someone now comes along and answers it, would I lose the tumbleweed badge ?

Another badge you could potentially lose is Unsung Hero for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular system type badges, such as Tumbleweed, Unsung, etc, once earned, stay on your profile. If you no longer meet the criteria, you don't lose them.

But if you later on do meet the criteria, you don't get them again, they'll just be credited from the first time you got them.

Tag based badges, those you get for reputation say in answering linux or printer questions, you can lose if you no longer meet the requirements, the tag is removed or merged (in those cases they may be transferred).

For more: [How do badges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)